# React, after fetching the data from my API, although my state has changed, the components did not get rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my code is seen below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import axios from 'axios';
import Group from './Group';


const Groups = () => {

  const [groupsData, setGroupsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/group/getGroups')
      .then(res => setGroupsData(res.data))
  }, [])

  console.log(groupsData)

  const groupsDisplay = groupsData.forEach((group) => {
    <Group key={group._id} />
  })

  

  return (
    <Box>
      <Button component={Link} to="./createGroup" variant="contained">
        Button Press
      </Button>
      <Group />
      {groupsDisplay}
      <Outlet />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Groups
```

After I used useEffect to fetch the data from my database, although the console.log(groupsData) did indicate that there is data, the groupsDisplay does not reflect this change on my DOM. May I know if there is anything I can do to change that? Thank you! Below is a picture of the console.log and my current DOM. The group on the screen is the  above the {groupsDisplay}, thank you.

[image]

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything, so `groupsDisplay` will be `undefined`. What you want is `.map()`, ensure you `return` from your callback if your giving your arrow function a body.

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you, that has solved my problem haha, I didnt expect to make 2 errors here ( forEach and the lack of return since im using { } ). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.map`, not `.forEach` to convert state to elements.

```
const groupsDisplay = groupsData.map((group) => <Group key={group._id} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the groupsDisplay variable. Currently, you are using the forEach method, which does not return anything. Instead, you should use the map method to create an array of JSX elements.